# Why is the row property of NSIndexPath a signed integer?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

Why is the row property of NSIndexPath a signed integer?

Could it ever take on a "valid" negative value?

[image]

**edit**

I haven't thought about this until today when I set LLVM to check sign comparison. This made the compiler spew out warnings whenever there was `indexPath.row <= [someArray count]` or similar.

Comment: it is readonly, so you don't care about it :) Why do you need negative values for row?

Comment: I don't need negative values for row, I'm just wondering why row isn't a NSUInteger.

Comment: "it is readonly, so you don't care about it"; you should, `initWithRow:section:` takes `NSInteger`s.

Comment: +1 Good question, my guess (kidding) is because Apple doesn't want you to use tables with more than 2,147,483,647 cells!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### What happens if you use negative numbers?

It isn't wise to use negative values, if you do, you'll get crazy results

```
NSIndexPath* path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:-2 inSection:0];
```

The above results in a section of 0, and a row of 4294967294 (which looks like underflow of an `NSUInteger` to me!) Be safe in the knowledge that this only occurs within the UIKit Additions category, and not within NSIndexPath itself. Looking at the concept behind `NSIndexPath`, it really doesn't make sense to hold negative values. So why?

### (Possible) Reason for why it is so

The core object `NSIndexPath` from OS X uses `NSUInteger`s for its indices, but the UIKit Addition uses `NSInteger`. The category only builds on top of the core object, but the use of `NSInteger` over `NSUInteger` doesn't provide any extra capabilities.

Why it works this way, I have no idea. My guess (and I stipulate *guess*), is it was a naive API slipup when first launching iOS. When `UITableView` was released in iOS 2, it used `NSInteger`s for a variety of things (such as `numberOfSections`). Think about it: This conceptually doesn't make sense, you can't have a negative number of sections. Now even in iOS 6, it still uses `NSInteger`, so not to break previous application compatibility with table views.

Alongside `UITableView`, we have the additions to `NSIndexPath`, which are used in conjunction with the table view for accessing it's rows and such. Because they have to work together, they need compatible types (in this case `NSInteger`).

To change the type to `NSUInteger` across the board would break a lot of things, and for safe API design, everything would need to be renamed so that the NSInteger and NSUInteger counterparts could work safely side by side. Apple probably don't want this hassle (and neither do the developers!), and as such they have kept it to `NSInteger`.

Comment: Wasn't the behavior changed between iOS 4 and iOS 5? I believe I was fixing some warnings with the transition.

Comment: Not sure, they API contracts certainly haven't been updated since iOS 2. The behaviour might have changed, but that shouldn't break the contract between the API and the user. The warnings might have been the compiler being a bit more smart in warning users what they might be getting themselves in for.

Comment: Nice addition of empirical evidence to the question but not an answer.

Comment: The answer is, we don't know (written as "Why it works this way, in that it allows NSInteger I have no idea."). There is no clear documentation or rationale available outside of Cupertino that explains why this is the way it is, we can only speculate. I believe the *empirical* evidence provided is reasonable, as using common sense I truly believe this was a slip up in API design. It doesn't make sense to have negative indices to sections and rows, but UITableView when released used these types. For `numberOfSections` to return a signed integer is crazy, for example.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason is that unsigned types underflow very easily. As an example, I had an `NSUInteger` variable for stroke width in my code. I needed to create an “envelope” around a point painted with this stroke, hence this code:

```
NSUInteger width = 3;
CGRect envelope = CGRectInset(CGRectZero, -width, -width);
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(envelope));
```

With an unsigned type this outputs `{{inf, inf}, {0, 0}}`, with a signed integer you get `{{-3, -3}, {6, 6}}`. The reason is that the unary minus before the `width` variable creates an underflow. This might be obvious to somebody, but will surprise a lot of programmers:

```
NSUInteger a = -1;
NSUInteger b =  1;
NSLog(@"a: %u, b: %u", a, -b); // a: 4294967295, b: 4294967295
```

So even in situations where it doesn’t make sense to use a negative value (stroke width can’t be negative) it makes sense to use the value in a negative context, causing an underflow. Switching to a signed type leads to less surprises, while still keeping the range reasonably high. Sounds like a nice compromise.

Comment: For `UITableView` to return `NSInteger` for a method such as a `(NSInteger)numberOfSections` makes sense to you? If you needed to perform arithmetic, convert the `NSUInteger` to `NSInteger` yourself. The table (and its respective `NSIndexPath`) needn't be concerned with the user level arithmetic.

Comment: Of course I can cast the number myself, the point is that I need to be aware of the problem to do that. An unsigned type really doesn’t offer any advantage here, does it?

Comment: It's conceptually correct; you can't have a negative number of sections, hence the type should try and enforce that.

Comment: Unsigned types don’t enforce anything, the compiler is happy with `NSUInteger foo = -1`. (Is there a warning for that?) It’s a documentation measure, nothing more. And all I’m saying is that given the potential headaches with sign overflow, I can understand why Apple would rather go with a signed type by default.

Comment: Then why would `NSArray count` return `NSUInteger` if they wanted to avoid the headaches of sign overflow? This is probably a more commonly used value in arithmetic to boot.

Comment: Yes, the SDK is not entirely consistent. Whatever reason we arrive at will be probably just a trifle that made some sense when designing the API and isn’t that important to be worth changing that way or other now.

Comment: I haven't thought about this until today when I set LLVM to check sign comparison. This made the compiler spew out warnings whenever there was indexPath.row <= [someArray count] or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think UIKit Additions on `NSIndexPath` use `NSInteger` type intentionally. If for some reason negative row would be passed as `parameter` to any method (I see none at the moment, though...), autocast to `NSIntegerMax + parameter` value would not happen and any possible object would not look for a ridiculously large parameter that does not exist. Still, there are other ways to prevent this, so it might be just a matter of taste.

I, for example, would not take `NSUInteger` as parameters in `NSIndexPath` class, but rather `NSInteger` and checked for a sign and wouldn't create `NSIndexPath` at all, if any parameter was negative.