# Swift Table: indexPath.row returns -1

Tags: swift

Every now and then, indexPath.row equals -1 when I swipe a row and enter `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` using the iOS Simulator. It is a very rare occurrence so it is hard to debug, beyond having `println(indexPath.row)` in code just waiting, which is how I know it is returning -1. Has anyone else had experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

The integer for `NSIndexPath` row is a signed `NSInteger`, instead of a `NSUInteger`. The reasoning for this *may* be because unsigned types can underflow easily. Which would mean an index path row of -1 would return a row value of about 4294967294.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586151/4487982) claims that the early versions of `UITableView` used `NSInteger` as an oversight and for Apple to change everything (number of sections, rows, etc.) to `NSUInteger` would be a huge undertaking to make the signed and unsigned types work together harmoniously.

If you have a situation in your code where you subtract 1 from `indexPath.row`, when the index is 0, this behavior will occur.

Comment: I see how that could happen but this is occurring while using a UITableView function; no math being done on `indexPath.row` what so ever. This is merely the case that the table is populated and swiping a cell to reveal edit options causes a crash because the view has returned -1 for the row. Even with a signed integer value the code should NOT be able to, in this case, return anything but values between 0 and (row.count-1)

Comment: @booksix Did you initialize your own indexPath object that you maybe using? The only other thing I could think of is maybe missing the `forSection` argument.