# How does NSNotFound work? ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c

Ok so I have several questions about `NSNotFound`:

1. How come `NSNotFound` is defined as `NSIntegerMax`?
2. How come apple uses signed instead of unsigned? Wouldn't it be
   smarter or better yet more logically convenient to use unsigned
   since the method it relates to if not found return a unsigned value
   neither-less.
3. Why is there a possibility for it to return either -1 or
   `NSIntegerMax`?

Comment: `NSNotFound` is used by a lot of methods across the Foundation and other frameworks, so 2 and 3 don't seem very relevant. What method are you referring to exactly ? As for 1, what is you proposed solution (keep in mind that `NSNotFound` can be used by methods that return an `NSInteger` or an `NSUInteger`).

Comment: We can only speculate about the reasons, you would have to ask Apple. It might have historical reasons. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585220/why-is-the-row-property-of-nsindexpath-a-signed-integer for a (remotely) similar question. – Your question #3 is unclear to me.

Comment: @MartinR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338295/why-nsnotfound-isnt-1-but-nsintegermax